# In Excel, how to download documents from embedded links and save them all locally

Tags: excel, download, vba

I have an excel spread sheet containing links to various MS word and PDF documents held on our Sharepoint site. These links are in one column. 
I am extracting the data from Sharepoint to burn to DVD.

What is the easiest way of downloading each document locally, collecting them together and changing the link in excel to point at the local file? The changed excel sheet and a folder of documents could then be burned to DVD. The excel sheet becoming something like and index for the documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The hardest part of the macro is to
  download the file from Sharepoint.
  Depending on the MOSS architecture
  and version, it should react
  differently. Thus, you may try what
  is described here :
  http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?threadid=163915

  - Then, you just have to create
    hyperlinks to the path of the file
    you have just downloaded, really well
    described here :
    http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/hyperlink-list.htm

Please feel free to post the first part of your work or further questions on the macro.